# Discord.py days since account creation autorole

Tags: discord, discord.py

Is there any way to check a users account creation date when they join a server and give them a role if their account is over 14 days old in discord.py?

Comment: Edit your question tags from discord.js to discord.py so you will get more competent answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

To check when a user joined use:

```
member.joined_at
```

This returns a datetime object, which allows you to use a timedelta to determine when the user should get the role:

```
joinedDate = member.joined_at
tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=14)
dateToAddRole = joinedDate + tdelta
```

You can then run a check with the new datetime object to see if the current date is the date the member should get the role

```
if datetime.now() == dateToAddRole:
    await member.add_roles(guild.get_role(roleid))
```